# Plural female gender of «Попутчик»

Tags: множественное-число, суффиксы

I got to learn that the word Попутчик means "fellow traveller"  (underlying a short piece of journey shared among two travellers). I was wondering what the female gender looks like, singular and plural. For example, if Попутчик is one fellow traveller and Попутчики are two or more of them, how can I express the same for the female case?

Comment: Is the question about "путник" or "попутчик"?

Comment: As far as I could understand, по-, or equivalently с-, to form the word Спутник, are prefixes but the main word, so to speak, remains путник. So that I thought that the suffix according to gender an numerosity would have displayed no variations

Comment: @Matteo But *попутчик* is not *попутник*... Obviously all these things are derived from *путь* but it's still quite far from just adding arbitrary prefixes and suffixes. Either way the current title is confusing (since the Q is solely about *попутчик* in the end).

Comment: You're right!  Sorry for the lapse, I edited the title. However, what about Попутчик and Попутник? How do these two item differ?

Comment: *However, what about Попутчик and Попутник? How do these two item differ?* - It's simple: *попутник* does not exist in Russian.

Comment: But спутник — спутница do exist.

Answer (score 5):

It's [`попутчица`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) in single and `попутчицы` in plural. More general, `-чик` has correspondence `-чица`. Be warned however, that it's not always an equally used feminine form and there's ongoing discussion to what extent we should use feminitives (see also [this](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19572/succinct-and-gender-neutral-russian-word-for-writer) question) in Russian.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helpful!